# No username displayed in task manager, what could be wrong with this XP SP3?

Tags: windows

When my computer is fully booted, I could see the username in task manager, except for `System Idle XXX`, what could be wrong:

[image]

The system was XP SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goto view -> select columns -> Now you can select User Name column there

so now you have user column.. Then then problem can be about services which explained [here](http://www.winxptutor.com/tmuserblank.htm) very well.. This should help you I guess.

Comment: The username column is already present I think, because the 'System Idle Process' has one

Comment: check the above link

Comment: This is really wired! How could TermServ has anything to do with it

Comment: That is what I am also wondering... :)